# NavigationStack and TabView - Toolbar and title not showing

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a problem regarding a TabView that is displayed inside of a NavigationStack. The TabView contains multiple views. Each view has its own navigationBarTitle and toolbar. The problem is that these views toolbar and navigation title are not shown. Just the content that is defined inside the views. I wrote the following code:

```
struct Home : View {
 var body some : View {
      NavigationStack {
          TabView(selection: $router.currentTab) {
            First()
                .tag(0)
            
            Second()
                .tag(1)
            
            Third()
                .tag(2)
            
            Fourth()
                .tag(3)
            
            Fifth()
                .tag(4)
        }
    }
 }
}
```

The First() view is defined the following (all other views are structured similar):

```
  struct First: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color("background").ignoresSafeArea(.all)
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 15) {
                    
                    WhatsNewView()
                    
                    FavoriteView()
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .refreshable {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                    newsService.getArticles()
                    simpleSuccess()
                }
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                UserButton()
            }
            
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                ToolbarRanking()
            }
            
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                ToolbarCalendar()
            }
            
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                ToolbarSearch()
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Home")
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix that problem?

Comment: Why do you need to wrap your `TabView` with a `NavigationStack`?

Comment: Because I want a global navigation and there should be only one navigationstack in a project

Comment: The TabView has to be at the top, it is in the human interface guidelines. Each tab can have its own stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TabView` should be your top-level view.

Each tab should then contain its own `NavigationStack`. e.g.

```
enum Router {
    case screenA, screenB
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView() {
            FirstScreen()
            
            NavigationStack {
                Text("second")
                    .navigationTitle("second")
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("second", systemImage: "2.circle")
            }
            NavigationStack {
                Text("third")
                    .navigationTitle("third")
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("third", systemImage: "3.circle")
            }
            NavigationStack {
                Text("fourth")
                    .navigationTitle("fourth")
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("fourth", systemImage: "4.circle")
            }

            NavigationStack {
                Text("fifth")
                    .navigationTitle("fifth")
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("fifth", systemImage: "5.circle")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FirstScreen: View {
    
    @State private var path: [Router] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            VStack {
                Text("first")
                NavigationLink("Screen A", value: Router.screenA)
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Router.self) { router in
                switch router {
                case .screenA:
                    VStack {
                        NavigationLink("Screen B", value: Router.screenB)
                    }
                    .navigationTitle("Screen A")
                    
                case .screenB:
                    VStack {
                        Button("Pop to root") {
                            path = []
                        }
                    }
                    .navigationTitle("Screen B")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("first")
        }
        .tabItem {
            Label("first", systemImage: "1.circle")
        }
        .task {
            print("First screen task")
        }
        .onAppear {
            print("First screen appears")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess that is not the solution for the problem. If you use NavigationStack(path: somePath) for each item in the TabView there is unexpected behavior using onAppear() and task() modifiers. These are getting called up to three times or more on a single appearance of a view. Also poping to root view is very laggy.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you how to use it with `NavigationStack(path:)` `.onAppear()` and `.task()` are called when tabs are switched, as expected. There is no lag when popping to root.