SwiftUI: NavigationStack with TabView: switching tab make the title animation to fail
I have 2 tabs in TabView in NavigationStack.
Each tab has ScrollView for all over the screen.
While switching between those tabs, the navigation title becomes not animated and stuck.
The attached sample code illustrates the problem:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab = 0
    @State private var navigationStack = NavigationPath()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navigationStack){
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                ScrollView {
                    Text("First tab content")
                }
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "1.circle")
                    Text("First")
                }
                .tag(0)
                
                ScrollView {
                    Text("Second tab content")
                }
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "2.circle")
                    Text("Second")
                }
                .tag(1)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Navigation Title")
            .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { route in
             //push new screen
            }
        }
    }
}
    
    

@main
struct MainTabbarApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}



Each tab gets its own NavigationStack, the TabView must be on top.

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75412096/navigationstack-and-tabview-toolbar-and-title-not-showing   There are many more posts/answers on this subject, search for them on SO.

@loremipsum if i add navigation stack for each tab, the next "pushed" screen displayed inside the TabView, and I want the new screen all over the Screen.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/toolbar(_:for:)

Works. Greate. 10x.
